# How to use value of html select element to sort collection in Shopify liquid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, liquid

I have the following html select element:

```
<div class="sort-collection-by">
<label for="sort-by">Sort by</label> 
<select id="sort-by">
    <option value="manual">Featured</option>
    <option value="price-ascending">Price: Low to High</option>
    <option value="price-descending">Price: High to Low</option>
    <option value="title-ascending">A-Z</option>
    <option value="title-descending">Z-A</option>
    <option value="created-ascending">Oldest to Newest</option>
    <option value="created-descending">Newest to Oldest</option>
    <option value="best-selling">Best Selling</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I want to use the chosen option in the following liquid tag where I have indicated SELECT_CHOICE_HERE.

```
{% assign sorted_products = collection.products | sort: SELECT_CHOICE_HERE %}
{% for product in sorted_products %}
```

I would like to have the sort action performed immediately when the select element value changes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Before posting here you should be checking the shopify docs. http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/add-drop-down-menu-to-sort-products-in-collections

Comment: @FunkDoc - that link doesn't address my question. I was trying a different implementation. Still wondering if it is possible to do it the way I suggested. Also, I may be wrong, but I think StackExchange recommends against responding by telling people to "Google it" or go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Funk Doc's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178648/how-to-use-value-of-html-select-element-to-sort-collection-in-shopify-liquid#comment-42872186) of following [this Shopify tutorial](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/add-drop-down-menu-to-sort-products-in-collections) is what I would have recommended too.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/11352987) (from the above tutorial) shows how to bind an event handler to the 'change' event on the `sort-by` dropdown, causing a sort to be triggered whenever the selected value in the dropodown changes:

```
jQuery('#sort-by').bind('change', function() {
  Shopify.queryParams.sort_by = jQuery(this).val();
  location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams).replace(/\+/g, '%20');
});
```

The reason this needs to be done in Javascript is because Liquid is rendered server-side, so this:

```
{% assign sorted_products = collection.products | sort: SELECT_CHOICE_HERE %}
```

...will have already been rendered before the user gets a chance to select a choice from the dropdown menu. Javascript is needed here to handle user events on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I can't follow that tutorial because my collection is within a Page and the URL query parameters have no effect on its sorting. I don't mind using Javascript, but I need a different method (not based on the query string). What are some other options? (Both liquid & Javascript are new to me.)

Comment: @MountainX That makes it more complicated. Instead of having the collection inside a page, could you use an [alternate collection template](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/store-wide/can-i-create-and-use-an-alternate-template-for-pages-products-collections-or-blogs)? That would be by far the simplest option I would think.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I'm mostly trying to learn something about Liquid and jQuery. If the final answer is that there is no way to directly pass the select choice as part of the Liquid, then that's really the answer I'm after. However, if there is a creative way to do what I was trying, I would appreciate knowing about it. Thanks.

Comment: @MountainX There's really no way to pass the user's choice to Liquid (because Liquid is rendered server-side before the page is presented to the user). Another way could be to use an AJAX request and then get the products from the returned HTML, but that wouldn't be straightforward either.